# I can't merge certain cells in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, merge

I have added a row into my report by right clicking the top row and selected add row above. Then when I try and merge all the cells in the new row it doesn't give me the option when I have selected all the cells and right click.

I can Merge 2 or 3 cells but not the whole thing.

My question is why cannot I not merge all the cells? Is there something in the a certain cell I can't see or a creation property that needs to be changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be an invisible lines between the row headers and the data, and also the column headers and the data. You cannot merge across these lines.

The solution is to keep you groups and delete the row and column headers. You can put the header rows inside the data area and you can merge cells too.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can only merge the cells from a row if you merge the cells from the row above.

```
    _____1__________2_________3____    
A  |__________|__________|_________|    
B  |__________|__________|_________|
```

Sometimes you can only merge B1-B2-B3 if you merge A1-A2-A3 first.

Comment: I don't know why, but it helped in my case. No grouping at all - just a plain table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This problem occure with grouping. You cannot merge across group lines. I have not had a problem merging when there is not a group. There is not a way around this.

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to create a header row for the whole table. you can create a separate table with 1 column and 2 rows and insert your table into the 2nd row of the new table. the 1st row can then be used as a header

Answer (score 1):

The left-most column has been auto-added as a group, so it can't be merged with cells to the right.  But you can delete that column and keep the grouping.

What I do is click on the second column (inside the grouping), then 'add column to left'. Then copy all of the Group fields from the left-most column into this new column, then delete the left-most group column. You should now be able to merge the cells.